# How to catch an my exception raise in Python and bounce it again

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, except

I'm trying to raise an handle exception, catch him and and raise it again.
The problem is I can't keep that exception and cause the program to stop again when I catch the exception.

I have tried this way and a few others and have not succeeded

```
try:

    if not (1 == 2):
        raise ValueError("This is my exception")


except Exception as error:

    raise ValueError(error)   # Trying to throw the previous exception
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just use raise CustomError("raising custom Exception") from error if you are using python3

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to raise the exception that was caught all you need to do is use `raise`

```
try:
    ...
except:
    raise  # this will re-raise the exception that was caught
```

Python 3 allows you to raise an [exception as the result of another exception](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/), giving you a traceback with more information as to the root cause

```
try:
    ...
exception Exception as e:
    raise CustomException('message') from e
```

Comment: Hi my friend, I have a lot of places I throw exceptions and once it's caught I want the appropriate message